# POST'ed data being read as empty in sign up script

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to build a sign up script with PHP for a website, however whenever I input information into one of the "input" tags, for some reason they're being returned as empty, although they really aren't.

In my signup.php I have created this form to post data:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="includes/signup-inc.php" method="post">
    <div class="">
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control transparent" placeholder="Your email here...">
        <input type="password" name="pwd" class="form-control transparent" placeholder="Your password here...">
        <input type="text" name="uid" class="form-control transparent" placeholder="Your username here...">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-fill">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Which brings the data over to my signup-inc.php file to allow a user to signup for an account. Whenever I try to signup for an account on my website, the error I created called "emptyInputSignup" keeps being thrown back.

This is what I have in my signup-inc.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
  $uid = $_POST["uid"];

  require_once 'dbh-inc.php';
  require_once 'functions-inc.php';

  if(emptyInputSignup($email, $pwd, $uid) !== false){
    header("location: ../signup.php?error=emptyinput");
    exit();
  }
```

And the function being referenced, which I have created in my 'functions-inc.php' is here:

```
<?php

function emptyInputSignup($email, $pwd, $uid){
  $results;
  if(empty($email) || empty($pwd) || empty($uid)){
    $results = true;
  }
  else {
    $results = false;
  }
}
```

Personally what I've done to try to debug to see if any data is in fact coming through is nulled the error handle which brings you back a page, to signup.php and instead echo'd a statement into the signup-inc.php page with the data being input. All 3 variables are echoed to the signup-inc.php page with the exact string written in the input field.

Any ideas on what I could be missing?

Comment: You have an answer which is correct, however in this circumstance I wouldn't even use a function, it is single purpose/use.  Just do the `if` without the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is it, but I don't see you actually return the result from the helper function.  I think you can simplify it a bit as well, maybe give this a try

```
<?php

function emptyInputSignup($email, $pwd, $uid){
  return empty($email) || empty($pwd) || empty($uid);
}
```

Comment: I'll see if I can troubleshoot with that! The main idea of the functions were to return either true or false to trigger the warning in the signup-inc.php

Comment: THANK YOU!! You were completely right, I forgot to return = $results!

Comment: @MeikeMagdalenaBüttner mind accepting the answer to close this out? Thanks :)